# Is the equals sign character "=" allowed in the value of an environment value in Linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, environment-variables

For example, I would like to use the following environment variable name and value in a Linux environment

```
myDN=OU=MY_OU,DC=MYDC,DC=local
```

Is the above allowed in a Linux environment?

Comment: Yes, environment variable values can contain any character except the null byte. There are restrictions on variable names, but not values.

Comment: Are you having a problem with that environment variable? If so, post the code so we can help you solve it.

Comment: Thank you Barmar.  I have a Linux development environment in which I can test this.  However, I'm sharing that environment with several others on my team, and I didn't want to disrupt their work in case the equals sign did not work for my environment variable value.  You have answered my question; if you post it as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: How would setting an environment variable in your login affect your colleagues?

Comment: The value here corresponds to a configurable pertaining to an LDAP connection.

Comment: So? You can set environment variables directly in the shell, you don't have to modify LDAP.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you.  I'm not modifying LDAP.

Comment: Then I'm not following you. What were you trying to avoid doing that would affect the rest of your team.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Environment variables can contain any character except `\0`, since the null byte is the C string terminator character. When parsing the environment, the first `=` in each environment variable separates the name from the value, but additional `=` characters have no impact.

```
barmar@dev:~$ export myDN=OU=MY_OU,DC=MYDC,DC=local
barmar@dev:~$ echo $myDN
OU=MY_OU,DC=MYDC,DC=local
```