# PHP - Does $setting need to be escaped in a 'putenv' call?

Tags: php, escaping, environment-variables

The `putenv` function takes a single argument, a string.  This string is expected to take the following format: `KEY=VALUE`.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php

Take the following code as a potential use case:

```
if(getenv(ON_SOME_ENVIRONMENT)) {

  // What happens if $dir contains an '=' character?
  $dir = dirname(__FILE__);

  putenv('SOME_KEY=' . $dir);
}
```

Does `$dir` in the above example need to be escaped?  If so, what kind of escaping needs to happen?

Comment: `putenv("A=B=C"); getenv("A")` returned me `B=C` so I guess not. Suprisingly `getenv("A=B")` returned `C` which is interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure the *right* answer, but I hope this can help.

In general, filtering user inputs depends on the context where the input is being used and what is a control character in that context. It seems that = is a control character that you want to avoid being interpreted as a control character, so that's one thing to filter. If there is an appropriate language built-in function you can use to do filtering that is the RIGHT one for that context then you should use that function. For example, as I guess you know, [escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) is the right thing to use for shell arguments before passing user input to `exec()`. I don't see a similar function to use before calling `putenv`. If you can make the filter based on an allowlist approach that's generally stronger. For example, just allowing ASCII alphabet from a-z would be a good way to allow English names without letting control characters sneak in for most scenarios.

Another strategy to protect against malicious input is to use an allowlist approach instead of (or in addition to) a filtering approach. So, if you know that accepted inputs are `ASCENDING` or `DESCENDING` then instead of providing a text box to users give them a dropdown and ensure that they selected either `ASCENDING` or `DESCENDING` before using it in the `putenv` function (ASCENDING and DESCENDING are random examples of things that might be expected, but adjust for your scenario). This doesn't work if the user input can be a wide variety of things, of course.

### Some practical tests:

It does seem like some of the behavior is version and/or platform dependent.

With PHP 7.3 on MacOS I got the same results as @michfuer.

Doing that same test on a ddev docker container running Linux `5.10.25-linuxkit` and PHP 7.4 I get different results:

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled
php > putenv('SOME_KEY=foo/bar=baz');
php > var_dump(getenv('SOME_KEY'));         // value "foo/bar=baz"
string(11) "foo/bar=baz"
php > var_dump(getenv('SOME_KEY='));        // value "foo/bar=baz"
bool(false)
php > var_dump(getenv('SOME_KEY=foo'));     // value "foo/bar=baz"
bool(false)
php > var_dump(getenv('SOME_KEY=foo/bar')); // value "foo/bar=baz"
string(3) "baz"
php > var_dump(getenv('SOME_KEY=blarg'));   // value "foo/bar=baz"
bool(false)
php > var_dump(getenv('SOME'));             // value false
bool(false)
```

Comment: I would imagine that a "graceful failure" such as throwing an exception might be the only safe way to ensure safety in this case.  Given how rare these corner cases seem to be, that seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the php `putenv()` is wrapping the C library function of the same name
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L894

The environment variable *value* can contain an `=`, but the *name* cannot, see

- [Is the equals sign character "=" allowed in the value of an environment value in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109789/is-the-equals-sign-character-allowed-in-the-value-of-an-environment-value-in)
- [Allowed characters in Linux environment variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821043/allowed-characters-in-linux-environment-variable-names)

Testing locally (macOS) on PHP 7.3

```
putenv('SOME_KEY=foo/bar=baz');
var_dump(getenv('SOME_KEY'));         // value "foo/bar=baz"
var_dump(getenv('SOME_KEY='));        // value "foo/bar=baz"
var_dump(getenv('SOME_KEY=foo'));     // value "foo/bar=baz"
var_dump(getenv('SOME_KEY=foo/bar')); // value "foo/bar=baz"
var_dump(getenv('SOME_KEY=blarg'));   // value "foo/bar=baz"
var_dump(getenv('SOME'));             // value false
```

`getenv()` disregarding the `=` string I think makes sense since that's a restricted character for the name.

So I don't think `$dir` needs any special escaping.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php 
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
putenv("ABC=$dir");

echo getenv('ABC');
```

output :

D:\project\demo